# Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite

Tags: jquery, angularjs, webpack

I am using AngularJS 1.5.10 and jQuery 2.2.4 with webpack. I have added jQuery and then AngularJS as mentioned in suggestions but it won't fix this issue.

I am getting console error as follows -

My login.conroller.ts file looks like

```
 import angular from 'angular';

(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('demo')
        .controller('LoginController', LoginController);

    LoginController.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$state', '$timeout'];

    function LoginController ($rootScope, $state, $timeout) {
        var vm = this; $timeout(function (){angular.element('#username').focus();});
 }
})();
```

My main.ts file is

```
import 'jquery';
import 'angular';
import 'angular-resource';
import 'angular-animate';
import 'angular-aria';
import 'angular-cache-buster';
import 'angular-cookies';
import 'bootstrap';
import 'angular-sanitize';
import '@uirouter/angularjs';
```

> [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite! See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element

Can anyone help me to resolve it?

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the code which caused the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error your code is unable to find jQuery. An alternative can be to use the standard DOM API.
Therefore instead of `angular.element('#username')` you can use `document.querySelector('#username');`

As suggested in the note given below from the [documentation for angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Note: Keep in mind that this function will not find elements by tag name / CSS selector. For lookups by tag name, try instead angular.element(document).find(...) or $document.find(), or use the standard DOM APIs, e.g. document.querySelectorAll().

Comment: `document.querySelector` definitely **WILL** find elements by tag name / CSS selector. The only difference is that it will select only the first element.

Answer (score 1):

The issue description is vague, but it looks like Angular can't find the correct jQuery instance in the global scope. When AngularJS is loaded, it looks for `window.jQuery` and if not found fallbacks to a built-in alternative that lacks the functionality of the selectors.

I assume that you're using webpack for for building your assets. If so, consider using an [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader).

Invoke:

```
$ npm install expose-loader --save-dev
```

And then add before angular imports:

```
import 'expose-loader?jQuery!jquery';
```